# Is there a simpler way to set multiple variables from a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I am attempting to set variables all at once from a list...

This is what I have so far:

```
firstName, lastName, age, email, pin, balance = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Something like:

```
firstName, lastName, age, email, pin, balance = row[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I know that won't work, but I'm just trying to figure out if something like that is possible :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the row has exactly six items:

```
userFirstName, userLastName, userAge, userEmail, userPIN, userBalance = row
```

If it might have more, just slice away the extras:

```
userFirstName, userLastName, userAge, userEmail, userPIN, userBalance = row[:6]
```

In Python 3, you can also unpack any excess items into a single variable:

```
userFirstName, userLastName, userAge, userEmail, userPIN, userBalance, *rest = row
```